# Why am I receiving an "unable to create media player" error when trying to play a looped alarm sound?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-mediaplayer, alarm

In an Android I am attempting to create an instance of [`MediaPlayer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) to play an alarm tone. I realize that there is an [alarmmanager](/questions/tagged/alarmmanager), but at this point I'm not interested in going to the trouble of creating a service. For now I'd like to grab the users default alarm tone load, loop and play it. Unfortunately my below code is causing the error (to to is not a typo):

> Unable to to create media player

Immediately before this error the following debug statement is logged:

> Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side

I've logged the path to the alert and it is listed as: `/system/alarm_alert`. As of now this code has only been run in an emulator targeted at Android 2.2 API Level 8. What is wrong with the below code that would cause this error?

```
Uri alert = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
if (alert == null) {
     // alert is null, using backup
     alert = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
     if (alert == null) {
         // I can't see this ever being null (as always have a default
         // notification) but just incase alert backup is null, using 2nd backup
         alert = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
     }
}

Log.d("alertPath", alert.getPath());

MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);

try {
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, alert);
    mediaPlayer.prepare();
    mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
    mediaPlayer.start();
} catch (IOException e) {

} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.d("mp", e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: I tested the code with real device targeted api level 7, and it works okay.

Comment: Most likely the problem here is that there are no ringtones or alarms installed to emulator, you would have to do it yourself.